# How Do I Store These User Inputs To Local Storage To Calculate With Them

Tags: html, wordpress, local-storage, elementor, calculation

My goal was to take a user input of a number value that they type in and take a user input of another number value that they use a slider to select.

I tried to store the values entered into local storage and calculate with those values imported to another script.

When I input the values in the preview page, the calculation stays at 0.

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

This is to store the value of number of employees.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Numeric Input Field Example</title>
    <style>
        /* Custom styling for the input field and placeholder */
        .numeric-input {
            width: 200px;
            padding: 8px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .numeric-input::placeholder {
            color: #999;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Numeric input field -->
    <input type="number" class="nmbrEmployees" name="nmbrEmployees" id="nmbrEmployees" placeholder="100" />

    <!-- Display the saved value -->
    <!-- <p>The entered value is: <span id="display-value1">0</span></p> -->

    <script>
        // Get the input field element
        const inputField1 = document.getElementById("nmbrEmployees");

        // Get the display element where we'll show the entered value
        const displayElement1 = document.getElementById("display-value1");

        // Event listener to update the display and save the entered value in local storage
        inputField1.addEventListener("input", function() {
            // Get the entered numeric value from the input field
            const enteredValue = inputField1.value;
            
            // Update the display element with the entered value
            displayElement1.textContent = enteredValue;

            // Save the entered value in local storage with the name "nmbrEmployees"
            localStorage.setItem("nmbrEmployees", enteredValue);

            // Trigger the storage event manually
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage"));
        });

        // On page load, retrieve and display the previously saved value from local storage
       // window.addEventListener("load", function() {
            const savedValue = localStorage.getItem("nmbrEmployees");

            if (savedValue !== null) {
                // If a value is found in local storage, display it in the input field and the display element
                inputField1.value = savedValue;
                displayElement1.textContent = savedValue;

                // Trigger the storage event manually
                window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage"));
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is to store the value percentage of employees in program.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Multiple Sliders Example</title>
    <style>
        /* Custom styling for the input field and placeholder */
        .numeric-input {
            width: 200px;
            padding: 0; /* Remove padding to align the slider handle with the beginning */
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .numeric-input::placeholder {
            color: #999;
        }

        /* Adjust the appearance and behavior of the slider */
        /* Remove the default styling */
        input[type="range"] {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
        }

        /* Set the track color and height */
        input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
            background-color: #ddd;
            height: 8px;
        }

        /* Set the slider thumb color, size, and shape */
        input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            background-color: #007bff;
            border-radius: 50%;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: -4px; /* Adjust the vertical position to align with the track */
        }

        /* Set the thumb color for Firefox */
        input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            background-color: #007bff;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 50%;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Slider input fields -->
    <input type="range" class="numeric-input slider" name="prcntIncreaseEmployees" id="prcntIncreaseEmployees" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" />
    <!-- Add more sliders as needed -->

    <!-- Display the entered values -->
    <p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<span class="display-value">0%</span></p>
    <!-- Add more display areas as needed -->

    <script>
        // Get all the slider elements
        const sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".slider");

        // Get all the display elements
        const displayElements = document.querySelectorAll(".display-value");

        // Function to update the displayed value
        function updateDisplayValue(index) {
            // Get the entered numeric value from the slider and convert it to a number
            const enteredValue = Number(sliders[index].value);

            // Update the display element with the entered value
            displayElements[index].textContent = enteredValue + "%";

            // Save the entered value in local storage with the name "prcntIncreaseEmployees"
            localStorage.setItem("prcntIncreaseEmployees", enteredValue);

            // Trigger the storage event manually
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage"));
        }

        // Loop through all sliders and add event listeners to each
        sliders.forEach((slider, index) => {
            slider.addEventListener("input", () => updateDisplayValue(index));
            slider.addEventListener("change", () => updateDisplayValue(index));

            // Update the displayed value initially with the default value of the slider
            updateDisplayValue(index);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is to make a calculation using those values I'm trying to store in local storage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculated Value Example</title>
    <style>
        /* Custom styling for the calculated value */
        h2 {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="calculated-value"></h2>

    <script>
        // Function to update the calculated value
        function updateCalculatedValue() {
            // Get the values from local storage
            const nmbrEmployees = localStorage.getItem("nmbrEmployees");
            const prcntIncreaseEmployees = localStorage.getItem("prcntIncreaseEmployees");

            // Calculate the result
            const calculatedValue = nmbrEmployees * (0.01 * prcntIncreaseEmployees) * 67;

            // Display the result in the h2 element
            const calculatedValueElement = document.getElementById("calculated-value");
            calculatedValueElement.textContent = calculatedValue.toFixed(0); // Remove decimals
        }

        // Call the function to update the calculated value initially
        updateCalculatedValue();

        // Listen for changes in local storage items
        window.addEventListener("storage", updateCalculatedValue);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of where the HTML is placed on my page.

[Here is a screenshot of where the HTML is placed on my page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Au1j.png)